# How to debug zone.js exception?

Tags: javascript, angular, zone.js

I have a Angular 2 TypeScript project. I have updated all of the packages and built the project.

Now I see this error in the console:

```
zone.js:1265 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.desc.get [as ontimeout] (zone.js:1265)
    at XHRLocalObject.AbstractXHRObject._cleanup (abstract-xhr.js:149)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (abstract-xhr.js:125)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (zone.js:1230)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)
```

So I can't figure out where the error is in the project code, because there is no project code in the stack trace. There are many HTTP requests at the start. They all succeed (no errors in the network tab), but I see that there is actually no data: no content for `<select>`. I would like to avoid having to go through my code, removing parts of it and testing whether the error is still there.

Is there any way to figure out where my code is causing this error?

Comment: Downgrade zonejs to 0.8.5 https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6036

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is a recent issue in the v0.8.8 of Zone.js. See the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6036) here. The easiest way for you to avoid this would be to downgrade to 0.8.5 version.

To do this, using npm, just use this command:

```
npm install zone.js@0.8.5
```

and consider adding `--save` at the end of the command to add it to your JSON dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Alexander is right: check your package.json if there is something like this in there:

... 
"zone.js": "^0.8...."

Change the version to something below 0.8.8. This fixed it for me.